# Query for existence of objects across two multi-to-one relationships

Tags: subquery, query

I have three relations. The first is "MyObject", which contains an integer "value" attribute as well as a foreign key to "Config". The relationship is "multiple MyObjects to one Config".

The "Config" relation contains basically just a name. Finally, there is the "ConfigKV" relation, having three attributes: a key, a value, and a foreign key to "Config". Each Config has multiple ConfigKVs.

This is the SQL statement to create the database:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyObject" (
  "value" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "cfg" INTEGER NULL,
  "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  CONSTRAINT "cfg_fk"
    FOREIGN KEY ("cfg")
    REFERENCES "Config" ("id"));

CREATE TABLE "Config" (
  "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);

CREATE TABLE "ConfigKV" (
  "key" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "value" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "cfg" INTEGER NULL,
  "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  CONSTRAINT "cfg_fk"
    FOREIGN KEY ("cfg")
    REFERENCES "Config" ("id"));
```

I want to query for all MyObjects that:

- has value 42
- the associated Config of which has *exactly* two ConfigKVs associated:

  - "Foo"->"Bar"
  - "Fuz"->"Baz"

Aside from the "exactly" part above, I can achieve that with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyObject
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * from ConfigKV WHERE key == 'foo' AND value == 'bar'
) as SQ1 on SQ1.cfg == MyObject.cfg
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * from ConfigKV WHERE key == 'fuz' AND value == 'baz'
) as SQ2 on SQ2.cfg == MyObject.cfg
WHERE MyObject.value == 42;
```

The inner joins neatly eliminate all MyObjects that do not have the required Key-Value mappings associated. However, I have no clue how to exclude MyObjects the config of which has a superset of the specified Key-Value mappings. Any idea here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So if the specific config has any other key-value pair (besides these 2), you want the object excluded from the results?

Comment: Also: `==` is not a valid SQL operator. I guess you mean `=`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. And thanks for the hint - my sqlite swallowed the "==".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this restriction with either a `NOT EXISTS` subquery or with `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM MyObject
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * from ConfigKV WHERE key = 'foo' AND value = 'bar'
) as SQ1 on SQ1.cfg = MyObject.cfg
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * from ConfigKV WHERE key = 'fuz' AND value = 'baz'
) as SQ2 on SQ2.cfg = MyObject.cfg
WHERE MyObject.value = 42
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM ConfigKV
        WHERE ConfigKV.cfg = MyObject.cfg
          AND NOT ( key = 'foo' AND value = 'bar'
                 OR key = 'fuz' AND value = 'baz'
                  )
      ) ;
```